# "this" keyword in JS - I'm confused

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I'm confused about `this` keyword in JS like below. Why `this.this_` is undefined in line 3) ? Any simple exalain for that ? In line 2) `this` points to Window object - i was suprised, but it is acceptable for me - why is that ? The only working for me is to use `this2_` variable, but i think that is not elegant. How to use `this` in good,elegant approach to always work and points to `O` object ?

```
var a = function(callback){
    callback('test');
};
var O = function(){
    this.val = 'abc';
    var this2_ = this;
    this.this_ = this;

    this.f = function(){
        console.log(this);           // (1) this -> O object, that's OK
        a(function(){           
            console.log(this);       // (2) this -> Window object
            console.log(this.this_); // (3) this.this_ -> undefined
            console.log(this2_);     // (4) this2_ -> O object
        });
    }
};
var o = new O();
o.f();
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why because `this` is not `this` inside that function.  Your comments show that.

Comment: `var this2_ = this;` is the way to do this. the reason is the scope changes within another function and `this` becomes something different. with `var this2_ = this` you are putting it into a local var that is within scope of the inner function.

Comment: Here's an explanation of 'this': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to "manage" the `this`, because it will change on different scopes. In this case, when you try to get the value in a new function, you are in a new scope, and the `this` refers to the window object.

you should use a new variable and try not to attach things to the `this`. Just use it for read-only reasons

NOTE: It is not impossible to do this (for example jQuery does a very good manage of the `this`) but it is not recommended.

So in your case, you could do something like this:

```
var O = function(){
    var this2;
    this2.this_ = this;
    this2.val = 'abc';

    this.f = function(){
        a(function(){       
            console.log(this2.val);   // (1) 'abc' 
            console.log(this2.this_); // (2) O object
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank You. I'm staying with `var this_ = this;` as the first line of code in object and using `this_` to access object instance in "all places". This is the easiest way i think.